# Is it necessary to verify checksum when data is sent over https

Tags: ssl, https, checksum

I am consuming the rest web service which is on HTTPS. Provider of the web service is sending checksum of the data sent over HTTPS. As the data sent over ssl is already encrypted and if the erroneous data is received, decryption will fail. So is it necessary to verify the checksum of the data?

Comment: Counterquestion: if you transfer a defective zip file over https: will https heal that file ?

Comment: No, It wont. But, my point is no error is introduced over the wire. If server sends a defective zip, I receive the same zip. no more errors are introduced.

Comment: @hnm: If you weren't using a zip, but a text file, how would you know if you had recieved a defective version of it without the checksum?  I believe md5/sha1 are broken from a security standpoint, but since it's already over https all you would be concerned about is the integrity of the file.

Answer (score 7):

It is necessary. TLS only guarantees the bytes written to the sending socket are the same bytes received in the receiving socket.

But what if the data is already corrupted before writing to the sending socket or the data is somehow corrupted by the receiver between the time of reading the data from the socket and you are trying to use the data? In this case, it is the receiving application's responsibility to check the checksum to guarantee the data received is the data expected.

In term of HTTP, the checksum could also serve the purpose of detecting the data corruption over the wire, but this functionality is covered by TLS in case of HTTPS. I think this the source of confusion and the reason why you asked this question.